# What is the closed form solution for this integral or series?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Here is the question:
$$F(n)=\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1-x\right)}{x^n}dx ;\ \ \ \ \forall \ n < 2$$

find the explicit expression of $F(n)$.

I find this relation:

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1-x\right)}{x^{n}}dx=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2-\left(n-1\right)k}$$

I try to solve using this identity:

$$\frac{\pi\tan\left(\pi x\right)}{2x}=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(k-\frac{\left(2n-1\right)}{2}\right)^2-x^2} \ \ ;  \forall \  n\in \mathbb{N} $$

but when I did this evaluation $x=\frac{\left(2n-1\right)}{2}$
the equality in the result is no longer met.

$$\frac{\pi\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(2n-1\right)\right)}{2n-1}=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2-\left(2n-1\right)k}$$

Does anyone know why equality is no longer fulfilled?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2780051/edit) the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $\log(1-x)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}$.  So, we have 

$$\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)}{x^n}\,dx=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k \int_0^1 x^{k-n}\,dx=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k-n+1)}$$

Comment: Did you just copy Mark Viola's comment, or did you really come up with that relation?

Comment: @FrankW. I really come up with that relation

Comment: Is $n$ an integer here?  Do we, for example, need to consider $n = 1.5$?

Comment: The sum you used doesn't work as well because it starts at $k=n$ while your sum starts at $k=1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the integral $I$. After partial fraction expansion of the sum that is mentioned, we see that 
$$I=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2-n}$$
From the series expansion of the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function):
$$\psi^{(0)}(z)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+z}$$
We can find that 
$$\boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)}{x^n}\,dx=\frac{\psi^{(0)}(2-n)+\gamma}{n-1}}$$

This result seems to agree with the numerical values that @marty cohen found.

EDIT:
If we take the limit as $n\to 1$, we can use l'Hopital's rule to conclude that
$$\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\,dx=\psi^{(1)}(1)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: What you could write as $\frac{H_{1-n}}{n-1}$ and $\to +1$

Answer (score 2):

This is more a comment.

Wolfy says:

$F(1) = -\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}
\approx -1.64493
$

$F(\frac12) = \log(16)-4
\approx -1.22741
$

$F(\frac32)
= -\log(16)≈-2.7726
$

$F(\frac23)
=\frac12 (\sqrt{3}\pi + 9 (\log(3) - 2))≈-1.3355
$

$F(\frac43)
 = \frac12 (\sqrt{3}\pi- 9 \log(3))≈-2.2231
$

$F(\frac53)
= \frac14 (-\sqrt{3}\pi - 9 \log(3))≈-3.8322
$

So something is going on
but I'm not sure what.